# How to apply padding to an HTML input element?

Tags: html, css

In the HTML layout shown in the following screenshot, I want the radio buttons exactly under the `Yes` and `No` labels, but the CSS `padding` property does not seem to apply to the HTML `input` tag. The code is given.

How can I change the *inline* `style` so that the radio buttons are under the Yes and No labels.

[**JSFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hzgw69vd/)

[image]

```
<html>
    <div style="padding:25px;">
        <div style="background-color:#bf5b5b; ">
            <label style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;">Yes</label>
            <label style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;">No</label>
            <label style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;"></label>
        </div>
        <div id="option_one_div" style="background-color:#74d4dd;">
            <input style="padding-left:125px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
            <input style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
            <label style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" for="option_one_div">Label of first group of Radio Buttons</label>
        </div>
        <div id="option_two_div" style="background-color:#36d666;">
            <input style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
            <input style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
            <label style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" for="option_two_div">Label of second group of Radio Buttons</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be super easy to use table in this situation. No?

Comment: I did achieve this using a table. But due to certain constraints I can not use tables.  @FaisalAshfaq

Comment: @Zarah what constraints?

Comment: @CameronMartin Actually it is going to be a part of a big HTML generated. There is going to be another `table` (entered by the user) in that HTML. I do not know any attributes like `id` etc. of that table; and at a later point, I extract that `table` and apply a `JS` function to column-sort it. So I can have just one `table` in the HTML, which is the `table` entered by the user.

Comment: Why not add margins? You can give `margin-left: 32px;`
`margin-right: 52px;` for both and get the desired result.

Comment: You cannot really style radio buttons - you need to style the label for the radio button instead, have a google for "styling radio buttons"

Comment: @Zarah But you have control over a direct parent element of that table, so you can still unambiguously select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea of `padding` is that it adds space within the element. You appear to be trying to add space outside the element, for which you should be using `margin`.

This image may help to explain the concept.

[image: box model example]
<sub>(source: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/box-model.gif))</sub>

The point is, to add space around an element you'd normally use margin rather than padding.
On a side note, a lot of people make this mistake when adding padding to the body; they use margin instead and it yields unpredictable results).

[Here's an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60kb0prm/) using your code, just with margin instead of padding (I modified the pixels to make it work properly).

Comment: I never understand this picture. Where are the boundaries of the actual element in there?Until I know what is the boundary of the actual element, I can't be sure what is inside it and what is outside it?

Comment: Margins generally are used to move that element away from other things, you cannot write in the margin. Anything from the border inwards you can modify.

Comment: I will admit, it can get confusing when you have elements with margins set within other elements that have padding/dimensions set and it can make no sense at first, but after a while you just get used to how it fits together.

Comment: @Thank you very much for the solution and the explanations. It really clarified my concept.

Answer (score 3):

Put `span` tag around `input` tags with left-padding:

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/hzgw69vd/2/)

Comment: it will have no effect. rather it will destry other alignment.

Comment: I have put JsFiddle. Have a look please!

Comment: after seeing that i am saying that.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3az1rmr/3/)

```
<input style="margin-left: 5%; padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
<input style="margin-left: 7.5%; padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
```

I used margin-left with percentage values. It looks like what you described you wanted - you can always replace percentage with pixel values if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is not solved in your Fiddle. You can say that the second radio button is not under No. The first one is also not exactly under Yes. Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/hzgw69vd/2/) by @FaisalAshfaq, I am referring to it so that you can see the difference.

Comment: It's true that my values could use some adjustment to get them perfectly in place, but they are aligned closely enough to see the basic principle. My answer follows the same principle as that submitted by AgentTadpole - you need to use margins, not padding. In my opinion his answer not only is correct but is the most instructive for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd div i.e.

```
<div id="option_one_div" style="background-color:#74d4dd;">
```

the

```
<input style="padding-left:125px; padding-right:25px;" type="radio" name="radio" value="0">
```

here padding-left has 125 px. change it to 25 px your prob will be solved.

Comment: What? `25px` was not working, so I added `125px` just to be sure. I just learnt that styling does not directly work on `input` elements at all! If you think what you said would work in the slightest, can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: So does it solve the problem? or make "any" difference?

Comment: I think it is your desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why not just do this:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <div style="background-color:#bf5b5b; width:100%; float:left;">
            <label style="width:15%; padding-left:3%">Yes<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:15%;">No<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:60%;">Label of first group of Radio Buttons</label>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#74d4dd; width:100%;  float:left;">
            <label style="width:15%; padding-left:3%">Yes<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:15%;">No<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:60%;">Label of teo group of Radio Buttons</label>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#36d666; width:100%;  float:left;">
            <label style="width:15%; padding-left:3%">Yes<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:15%;">No<input type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></label>
            <label style="width:60%;">Label of three group of Radio Buttons</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Then just add some @ media css classes to make it full mobile responsive and stack-able too.

This will offer much more to you prospective site users as they can view it from their mobile devices with as much ease as they can from a pc.